# How to load images from cache for the offline page?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, caching, offline, service-worker

So I'm trying to figure out how to load a cached image for my offline.html page in my Rails app. I have two issues:

1. I'm not sure where exactly to keep the images.
2. I'm not sure how to properly load the image's source `img src="???"`.

My `serviceworker.js.erb` is currently caching the image properly:

```
function onInstall(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function prefill(cache) {
      return cache.addAll([
        '<%= asset_path "base.js" %>',
        '<%= asset_path "minimal.css" %>',
        '/offline.html',
        '<%= asset_path "cute-cat.png" %>',
        '<%= asset_path "cute-dog.png" %>',
      ]).then(function () {
        console.log("WORKER: Install completed");
      });
    })
  );
}

function onFetch(event) {
  if ( requestBlackListed(event.request) ) { return; }
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(function (cached) {
      if (cached && shouldReturnStraightFromCache(event.request.url)) {
        return cached;
      }
      return fetch(event.request)
        .then(fetchedFromNetwork)
        .catch(function fallback() {
           return cached || caches.match("/offline.html");
         })
      }
    )
  );
```

and my `offline.html` looks pretty much like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>You are not connected to the Internet</title>
  <meta property="og:url" content="offline.html" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Looks like you've lost your Internet connection" />
</head>
<body>
  <!-- This file lives in public/offline.html -->
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <a href="/"><img src="/app/assets/images/cute-cat.png"/></a>
      <img src="/app/assets/images/cute-dog.png" />
      <p>You're offline!.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The images are currently loading from `/app/assets/images/`, but it doesn't work. I think the smarter solution would be to load the two images from the cache as opposed to the assets folder. Any ideas would be great.

EDIT: Added fetch handler (`onFetch` function).

Comment: Show us your `fetch` handler. How do you serve the cached images? Do you?

Answer (score 0):

By right, you load your image as if the page was online.

1. I'm not sure where exactly to keep the images. - Let the SW handle it.  Just declare the path properly in your SW as if you were loading them online.  It should be relative to where your SW is.
2. I'm not sure how to properly load the image's source img src="???". - Treat your offline page as if it was online.  The SW will look for the assets if it has been cached or not.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. My issue is that I wouldn't be able to use erb, and I'm currently caching the image via `asset_path`. Normally what I would do is use erb for the img src, like so: `<img src=<%= asset_path "cute_dog.png" %>`, but I'm not sure how to properly link the `src` from the assets folder.

Comment: This response is not an actuall awnser.